# Matlab tifflib code explination

Tags: matlab, image-processing, tiff

I find that importing in large multi-tiff files through the imread function is slow for what I need to do. I used googlefoo and located a [tutorial](http://www.matlabtips.com/how-to-load-tiff-stacks-fast-really-fast/) explaining a faster way to load tif files. I tried to use the code (below) but it keeps crashing halfway through. As the tutorial stated, might have to change the code based on what I'm trying to load, and this is where I am stuck. I do not know enough about the tifflib to try and change the code.

Would anyone be able to help explain the code so I know where to start with processing the data.

```
InfoImage=imfinfo('file.tif');
mImage=InfoImage(1).Width;
nImage=InfoImage(1).Height;
NumberImages=length(InfoImage);
FinalImage=zeros(nImage,mImage,NumberImages,'uint16');
FileID = tifflib('open',loaderpath,'r');
rps = tifflib('getField',FileID,Tiff.TagID.RowsPerStrip);

for i=1:NumberImages
   tifflib('setDirectory',FileID,i);
   % Go through each strip of data.
   rps = min(rps,nImage);
   for r = 1:nImage
      row_inds = r:min(nImage,r+rps-1);
      stripNum = tifflib('computeStrip',FileID,r);
      FinalImage(row_inds,:,i) = tifflib('readEncodedStrip',FileID,stripNum);
   end
end
tifflib('close',FileID);
```

Tiff file format

```
Filename                      'img_stack.tif'
FileModDate                   '25-Oct-2017 09:31:40'
FileSize                      49960190
Format                        'tif'
FormatVersion                 []    
Width                         1280
Height                        720
BitDepth                      8
ColorType                     'grayscale'
FormatSignature               [73,73,42,0]
ByteOrder                     'little-endian'
NewSubFileType                0
BitsPerSample                 8
Compression                   'PackBits'
PhotometricInterpretation     'BlackIsZero'
StripOffsets                  1x66 double
SamplesPerPixel               1
RowsPerStrip                  11
StripByteCounts               1x66 double
XResolution                   72
YResolution                   72
ResolutionUnit                'Inch'
Colormap                      []
PlanarConfiguration           'Chunky'
TileWidth                     []
TileLength                    []
TileOffsets                   []
TileByteCounts                []
Orientation                   1
FillOrder                     1
GrayResponseUnit              0.0100000000000000
MaxSampleValue                255
MinSampleValue                0
Thresholding                  1
Offset                        19840
```